# Organizar array em ordem alfabética

Tags: php, array

Bom quando quero organizar um array em ordem alfabética com base em um campo do array eu faço assim:

```
// Compara se $a é maior que $b
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a['nome'] > $b['nome'];
}

// Ordena
usort($produtos, 'cmp');
```

Isso funciona perfeitamente, porém queria simplificar tudo em uma única função, para facilitar quando eu a chamar.

Tentam fazer assim:

```
    function Ordena_Array ($array, $campo) {

    // Compara se $a é maior que $b
    function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a[$campo] > $b[$campo];
    }

    // Ordena
    return usort($array, 'cmp');
}
```

Exemplo de como eu tentei fazar

```
 $array = array(
array( 'nome' => 'Alexandre',   'idade' => '65' ),
array( 'nome' => 'Alex',    'idade' => '33' ),
array( 'nome' => 'Zezinha', 'idade' => '29' ),
array( 'nome' => 'Rosana',  'idade' => '64' )
);

function Ordena_Array ($array, $campo) {

    // Compara se $a é maior que $b
    function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a[$campo] > $b[$campo];
    }

    // Ordena
    return usort($array, 'cmp');
}


// Mostra os valores
print_r( Ordena_Array ($array, "nome") );
```

Erros :

```
NOTICE Undefined variable: campo on line number 14

NOTICE Undefined index:  on line number 14
```

Nota: Estou usando o PHP 7.2

Comment: Esse problema é pq vc tá colocando uma string no lugar de um parâmetro na função `Ordena_Array`.

Comment: Qual versão do PHP você está usando?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta, não esta muito clara.

Comment: Pronto alterei a pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível.

E é possível simplificar esse código usando [Closures](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.closure.php) (ou funções anônimas).

Seu problema é que a closure interna não tem acesso à variável `$campo`. Isso ocorre por causa do escopo, então você precisa dar acesso a essa variável para a Closure interna (usando `use`).

Outra questão é que você precisa modificar a array dentro da função e retorná-la, e não retornar o resultado da função `usort` diretamente.

Faça assim:

```
<?php

function Ordena_Array($array, $campo) {
    usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($campo) {
        return $a[$campo] > $b[$campo];
    });
    return $array;
}

$array = array(
    array( 'nome' => 'Alexandre',   'idade' => '65' ),
    array( 'nome' => 'Alex',    'idade' => '33' ),
    array( 'nome' => 'Zezinha', 'idade' => '29' ),
    array( 'nome' => 'Rosana',  'idade' => '64' )
);

var_dump(Ordena_Array($array, "nome"));
```

Sugiro não nomear funções com letras maiúsculas em PHP pois foge da convenção de nomenclatura das funções.

Sugiro usar `ordena_array`.

Fiddle: https://ideone.com/ygGstF

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela dica. Deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Existem duas questões na sua implementação.

O primeiro, que é o erro que você está recebendo, é que a variável `$campo` não está disponível quando a função é executada. A variável deve ser adicionada ao contexto da função. Nesse caso, você pode usar *funções anônimas* e utilizar o `use` para adicionar a variável:

```
// Compara se $a é maior que $b
$callback = function ($a, $b) use ($campo) {
    return $a[$campo] > $b[$campo];
};

// Ordena
usort($array, $callback);
```

O outro ponto, é que `usort` retorna um `boolean` e não o `array` ordenado. O `array` é ordenado por referência, logo, deve retornar o `array` que foi passado como parâmetro:

```
function Ordena_Array ($array, $campo) {
    // Compara se $a é maior que $b
    $callback = function ($a, $b) use ($campo) {
        return $a[$campo] > $b[$campo];
    };

    // Ordena
    usort($array, $callback);

    return $array;
}
```

Código em funcionamento: https://3v4l.org/oMtYS

Answer (score 0):

**SE DESEJA ORDENAR E TAMBEM ALTERAR O INDICE:**

Segundo a documentação do PHP: [PHP SORT](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sort.php)

```
<?php

$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
sort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}

?>
```

O retorno será:

> fruits[ 0 ] = apple
>   fruits[ 1 ] = banana
>   fruits[ 2 ] = lemon
>   fruits[ 3 ] = orange

**O array foi ordenado em ordem alfabética com alteração nos índices**

**SE DEDEJA ORDENAR E MANTER O INDICE:**

Segundo a documentação do PHP: [PHP ASORT](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.asort.php)

```
<?php
$frutas = array("d" => "limao", "a" => "laranja", "b" => "banana", "c" => "melancia");
asort($frutas);
foreach( $frutas as $chave => $valor ){
    echo "$chave = $valor\n";
}
?>
```

O retorno será:

> b = banana
>   a = laranja
>   d = limao
>   c = melancia

**O array foi ordenado em ordem alfabética, os índices foram mantidos**

Comment: Ok, mas não quero dar um echo no resultado quero manter a variável `$array` para ser utilizada em um relatório.